# Tomcat Servlet FileUpload and UTF-8

Tags: java, servlets, file-io, encoding, utf-8

I am using commons FileUpload to get client headers. I am trying to use the header Strings to write txt content like:

> StringA; StringB; "ciryllic word"

The server localization is ru_RU.utf-8 the client is cp1251... The result is I always get on my client (desktop app)

> StringA; StringB; ?????

instead of cyrillic characters in my server txt files lines. If I open txt with my IE 8 and watch the encoding the cyrillic content can be readable with utf-8 encoding only :( So my question is what should me do to make my servlet write ru_RU.utf-8 acceptable strings. I am testing it on windows so I need to know it for sure

Please help me to understand

Any useful comment is appreciated

Comment: Oh, my... Nobody knows what the encoding is :)

Answer (score 1):

`ServletOutputStream out =response.getOutputStream();

out.write((YOUrfileasstring).getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but to answer this part -

> So my question is what should me do to make my servlet write ru_RU.utf-8 acceptable strings.

You should use either of two methods provided by the HttpServletResponse class.  Those are:

setContentType(), e.g.

```
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

or,

setCharacterEncoding(), e.g.

```
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

There are other examples for those methods and information on when to use them all over the place.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't help on the server side :( I've tried it already but hopeless... Another suggestion?

Comment: I just thought maybe I need to check the locale or encode the text with new String("",enc)? But I am not sure?

Comment: ... and, yes, I have already tried the  response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
 etc but it doesn't help... But why it doesn't help?